# related width of two elements

Tags: php, html, width

I want to relate the width of two elements, the first is a simple div, the second is a span.

```
<div id="wb_Name_To_Menu" style="position:absolute;left:768px;top:20px;width:171px;height:18px;z-index:4;">
<span id="sp_Name_To_Menu" style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;">Love Me!</span></div>    
<div id="Layer_to_mainu" style="visibility: hidden;position:absolute;text-align:left;left:772px;top:22px;width:132px;height:135px;z-index:132;" title="">
    <div id="wb_main_mainu" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:9px;width:123px;height:28px;z-index:1128;padding:0;">
    <div id="main_mainu">
    <ul style="display:none;">
    <li><span></span><span id="id_full_name_from_main_menu">love&nbsp;Meeeeee</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span></span><span>Account&nbsp;Sitting</span></li>
    <li><span></span><span>Help</span></li>
    <li><span></span><span>Log&nbsp;Out</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wb_Name_To_Menu").hover(function(){ 
    $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("visibility","visible");  
    $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("width",$("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width()+"px");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Layer_to_mainu").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("visibility","hidden");
  });
});
```

it doesn't work! and I know the cause: it is caused by `$("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width()` which results in a null value!

Comment: I don't have a solution for your problem but note that you are trying to get the width of element which parent has `display: none` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width()` returns 0 because its ancestor `<ul>` has `display:none` set. To read the width you might want to just remove that attribute, or you could temporarily change it in the js, depending on what you're trying to do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wb_Name_To_Menu").hover(function(){ 
  $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("visibility","visible"); 
  $("#main_mainu > ul").css("display","block");
  $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("width",$("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width()+"px");
  $("#main_mainu > ul").css("display","none");
});
```

That won't display your text but it will update the width of #id_full_name_from_main_menu,
you would need to remove the `display:none` to see your text appear.

Comment: your answere is true , but i make one change of it :
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wb_Name_To_Menu").hover(function(){ 
   $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("visibility","visible"); 
  $("#main_mainu > ul").css("display","block");
  $("#Layer_to_mainu").css("width",$("#sp_Name_To_Menu").width()+10); 
  $("#main_mainu > ul").css("display","none"); 
  });
});
and now it work 100% ... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `+"px"` On line 4 of the script you provided it seems to work.

`$("#Layer_to_mainu").css("width",$("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width());`

Comment: No ... isnt the cause , i write :
 alert($("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width()); ... 
value of $("#id_full_name_from_main_menu").width() = null !!!